# Remove List items from List with Removeall Lambda Hashset

Tags: c#, lambda, hashset, predicate, removeall

I'm using FileHelpers to parse 2 text files that contain active directory user information the Users class is defined as:

```
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]

public class Users
{
    public string LogonName;

    public string DisplayName;

    public string FirstName;

    public string LastName;

    public string SamAccountName;

    public string Password;

    public string Identity;

}
```

The CSV files contain LogonName,DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,SamAccountName,Password,Identity
MM0123,Mothhair Mayeye,Mathhair,Mayeye,MM0123,secrtpwd,Group1

Most of the users in both files are identical. There are around 6500 records.

I'm expecting that after this runs:

```
        List<Users> UserListCur = new List<Users>();
        List<Users> UserListLR = new List<Users>();
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Users));

        var records = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\\users.csv");
        var lrrecords = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\\lastrun.csv");

        foreach (Users record in records)
        {

            UserListCur.Add(record);
        }

        foreach (Users record in lrrecords)
        {

            UserListLR.Add(record);
        }


        UserListCur.RemoveAt(0);
        UserListLR.RemoveAt(0);


        var UserListLRhash = new HashSet<Users>(UserListLR);
        UserListCur.RemoveAll(x => UserListLRhash.Contains(x));
```

The entries from UserListLR should be removed from UserListCur but UserListCur is not changed. Most of the user entries are identical so I'm not sure why it's not removing any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` in users to define what makes two users equal or you must write a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Users>` and pass that class in to the constructor of the HashSet you created.

When you just use the default implementation of equality like your code currently does the only way two users will be considered equal is if `Object.RefrenceEquals(user1, user2)` returns true.

Here is a example creating a comparer and passing it in.

```
public sealed class UsersEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Users>
{
    public bool Equals(Users x, Users y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.LogonName, y.LogonName) && string.Equals(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName) &&
               string.Equals(x.FirstName, y.FirstName) && string.Equals(x.LastName, y.LastName) &&
               string.Equals(x.SamAccountName, y.SamAccountName) && string.Equals(x.Password, y.Password) &&
               string.Equals(x.Identity, y.Identity);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Users obj)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (obj.LogonName != null ? obj.LogonName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.DisplayName != null ? obj.DisplayName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.FirstName != null ? obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.LastName != null ? obj.LastName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.SamAccountName != null ? obj.SamAccountName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.Password != null ? obj.Password.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.Identity != null ? obj.Identity.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

and your code changes to

```
    List<Users> UserListCur = new List<Users>();
    List<Users> UserListLR = new List<Users>();
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Users));

    var records = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\\users.csv");
    var lrrecords = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\\lastrun.csv");

    foreach (Users record in records)
    {

        UserListCur.Add(record);
    }

    foreach (Users record in lrrecords)
    {

        UserListLR.Add(record);
    }


    UserListCur.RemoveAt(0);
    UserListLR.RemoveAt(0);


    var UserListLRhash = new HashSet<Users>(UserListLR, new UsersEqualityComparer());
    UserListCur.RemoveAll(x => UserListLRhash.Contains(x));
```

Comment: I snagged your first example with the IEquatable inheritance, overloaded Equals and overridden GetHashCode and it seems to work exactly as I expected.  Why is the second example better?

Comment: Personal preference. When working with HashSets or Dictionary keys the class you are comparing must be Immutable while it is in the collection. If I am not working with a class I know will be immutable I tend to try to avoid overriding GetHashCode and Equals. Look at the "Notes to Inheritors" section of the [documentation for GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx#Inheritors) for some more details.

Comment: using equality operator `==` instead of this overload of `string.Equals` probably makes for a better readability. Also, using null conditional member access also improves readability `obj?.DisplayName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0`

Comment: Please also note the `NullReferenceException` that will occur in `public int GetHashCode(Users obj)` when you pass `null` argument

Comment: @ironstone13 yea, i was just using the tool from Resharper to generate it, if this was production code I would have made some changes.

Comment: @ironstone13 also, good catch, if the argument is null [the contract for the interface states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.gethashcode.aspx#Anchor_1) you should be throwing a `ArgumentNullException` not a `NullRefrenceException`. I will update the answer to fix that part.